# Replace characters in xlsx file with Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm very new to Python and hoping someone can help me.  I am trying to replace specific characters within a xlsx document.  The values are spread across the whole worksheet and are not always ASCII characters.  I'm trying to loop through every character, in every cell, in every row in the sheet to find and replace the values then save the updates.

```
import openpyxl
xlsx = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
sheet = xlsx.active

for row in sheet:
    for cell in row:
        for element in cell:
            if ord(element) ==188:
                element.replace(chr(188), '1/4')
xlsx.save('workbook.xlsx')
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Are there errors or are you looking for a better way to replace non ASCII characters?

Comment: I'm currently getting TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable.  So either a way to resolve my current error, or a better way to replace non ASCII characters with set counter parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the TypeError, you need to do `cell.value`.

To replace non ASCII characters, you could create a dictionary.

```
replace_dict = {
    'something': 'replace_with_this',
    'something_else': 'replace_with_this'
}

if cell.value in replace_dict: 
    element = replace_dict[cell.value]
```

But that's kind of tedious to have to define everything, I would prefer to do this which will return a string where non ASCII characters have been replaced:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def replace_non_ascii(string):
    return unidecode(string)
```

In the future when you ask a question on StackOverflow, make sure to include your errors, it will be easier to help you.